# How can I get all data of post with multiple images from multiple table in jQuery ajax Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I wanna get all posts with multiple images data from post table & image table by Ajax "GET" method & wanna show in a view page in Laravel project without reload/refresh page. but I'm facing some error's. My controller code

```
public function getposts(){
      //make one array o all table data
      $array = [];
      //post table data
      $array['posts']=[];
      $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
      $array['posts']=$posts;

      foreach ($posts as $post) {
         $postid = $post->id;
         //image table data
         $array['images']=[];
         $images = PostImage::where('post_id', $postid)->get();

         foreach ($images as $image) {
           $image .= "<img src='public/images/posts/' .$images >";
          }
            $array['images']=$image;
        }

      return response()->json([
        'posts'=>$array,
            ]);    
    }
```

**jQuery code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
  });
//fetch all posts
 getPosts();
 function getPosts(){
   $.ajax({
     url: '/fetch-posts',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,

     success: function(data){
      // console.log(data.posts.posts);
      // console.log(data.posts.images);
      $('table tbody').empty();
      $.each(data.posts.posts, function(key, item){
              $('table tbody').append('<tr> \
              <td>' + item.id + '</td> \
              <td>' + item.text + '</td> \
              <td>' + item.publish_type + '</td> \
              <td>' + item.image + '</td> \
              </tr>');

              let image="";
              let i = item.id;
              // console.log(i);
              for(i=0; i<data.posts.images.length; i++){
                image+=data.posts.images[i]+ "";
                // console.log(image);
                  $('#postImagesShow').html(image);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
        });
</script>
```

How can I apply eloquent relationship by jquery ajax at laravel?

Comment: share posts and images DB schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [One to Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in Laravel

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Post extends Model


public function images()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}


// then in your controller you can say:
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('images')->get();
```

Comment: well...how I will catch & show those post images at jquery codes?

Comment: You can send the JSON response from your controller method to frontend like so: ```return response->json(['posts' => $posts]);```

Comment: done...problem is in jQuery scripts to print images on html view page

Comment: what is the output of  ```console.log(data.posts.images);```?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/TuI14IgG0FWY